# Group Array with count

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, underscore.js

I have an array of items that contains several properties. One of the properties is an array of tags. What is the best way of getting all the tags used in those items and ordered by the number of times that those tags are being used on those items? I've been trying to look to underscore js but not getting the expected results.

```
return _.groupBy(items, 'tags');
```

Example of my data:

```
item1
 - itemName: item1
 - tags(array): tag1, tag2

item2
 - itemName: item2
 - tags(array): tag1, tag3
```

so I'm trying to get something like `{tag1, 2}{tag2, 1}{tag3, 1}`

Update: My tag contains a ID and a name. I'm trying to group by those IDs

Comment: What is `{tag1, 2}{tag2, 1}{tag3, 1}` supposed to be? It's not a valid array or object.

Comment: @Phil You are right. Just trying to get a way of getting how many times a tag is being used. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simply using a reduce operation. For example

```js
var items = [{
  itemName: 'item1',
  tags: [
    {id: 'tag1', name: 'Tag 1'},
    {id: 'tag2', name: 'Tag 2'}
  ]
}, {
  itemName: 'item2',
  tags: [
    {id: 'tag1', name: 'Tag 1'},
    {id: 'tag3', name: 'Tag 3'}
  ]
}];

var tags = items.reduce((tags, item) => {
  item.tags.forEach(tag => {
    tags[tag.id] = tags[tag.id] || 0;
    tags[tag.id]++;
  });
  return tags;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tags, null, '  ') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Tried to implement this code but I'm getting Object {[object Object]: 3} Is this expected? I'm not sure how to get the count per tag

Comment: @Snapper How are you *"getting"* that (hopefully not via `alert()`)? What **exactly** does your `items` array look like?

Comment: Sorry about that. I realized that my tags array is slightly different from what I initially posted. Will update

Answer (score 3):

Map all tag arrays into a single array, and then `countBy`

```
var tags = _.flatten(_.map(items,d=>d.tags))
tags = _.countBy(tags)
```

Using underscores `chain` utility

```
var tags = _.chain(items).map(d=>d.tags).flatten().countBy().value();
```

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. Implemented this and got the same result as in the other answer below @Phil. Object {[object Object]: 3} How can I get then get the tags and how often they are being used?

Comment: Your data structure must differ from the ones me and Phil used, b/c i checked his answer out of curiousity. Look at my jsfiddle and see if we're using the same data https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/ppfLwhyx/1/

Comment: Thanks for the code @Eric Guan, made me realize that my structure is not exactly how I initially posted. Will update.

Comment: Beautiful answer. I think that `countBy`  should be `countBy('id')` and that mapping could be replaced with `pluck('tags')`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too:

```
var tagGroup =
  items.reduce(function(p, c){
      c.tags.map(function(tag){     
        p[tag] = p[tag] || {count:0};         
        p[tag].count++;
        return p;
      });

      return p;
  }, {});
```